# adding a variable to a partial template

Tags: variable, template-partials

I am using creating template parts (header, footer) but would like to know how I can add a variable, a body class to individual templates.

I see people are using stash but is there another way to set a variable on a per-page basis.

Thanks

Comment: strategy is depended on you template structure - what do you use? Snippets/embed/GV? Based on what parameters  you want to add this body class? URI segment? Or may be u just need {preload_replace:variable_name="replacement"} ? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/preload_replacement.html#creating-and-using-an-preload-replacements

Answer (score 3):

The easier and faster way to do this is using [Preload Text Replacements](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/preload_replacement.html) and [snippets](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/snippets.html).

Snippets are parsed [before](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html) Preload Text Replacements. So you can put them inside snippets.

Let me show you an example.

This is part of a snippet called `doctype-and-styles-snip`:

```
{preload_replace:pre-rootclass=""}<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js no-jquery {if segment_1 == ""}home{/if} {pre-rootclass}">
<head>
[...]
```

I put the `CLASS` on `HTML` instead of `BODY`, but the principle is the same. The `{preload_replace:pre-rootclass=""}` is intended to remove the unused `CLASS`.

On templates, you can use something like this:

```
{doctype-and-styles-snip}
{exp:channel:entries limit='1' require_entry='yes' disable='pagination' [...]}
<title>{title} - {site_name}</title>
{header-snip}
[...]
```

When you need a custom class, just add a `preload_replace` before the snippet. For example, this is a 404 page:

```
{preload_replace:pre-rootclass="404"}{doctype-and-styles-snip}
<title>Not found - {site_name}</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow,noarchive" />
<meta name="description" content="not found" />
{header-snip}
[...]
```

This way, you can have custom classnames per page avoiding embeds and stash.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add another way round this which might be helpful:

You could do something like this if you wanted to use the partial in lots of places but maybe change its styling a little depending on template (without use of conditionals).

In the template:

```
{preload_replace:pre_s_block_class='template_specific_class'}
{s_block}
```

In the snippet {s_block}:

```
<div class="{pre_s_block_class}">
... content ...
</div>
```